# Jmeter Module Controller - Response Assertion Ignored

Tags: jmeter

In a test Fragment add a Simple Controller

In the Simple Controller Add add a request

In a Module Controller reference that simple controller

Add a Response Assertion within the module

The Response Assertion is Ignored.

Is this a normal behavior ? If yes, you shouldn't be able to add a Response Assertion.

Comment: Can you post how your script looks like? For example I'm not clear why do you reference Response Assertion under module, and not under request which creates the response you are asserting?

Comment: That is because the response could vary, for example you could use the module within a parameterized controller,and the response can be different for each request.That's why I would prefer to put the response assertion under module controller. There is also a possibility if you are using the parametrized controller to parametrize the response as well,but it would be easier to do that within the module

Comment: Then you definitely need to provide more details. No idea what you are doing. For example you say "response can be different for each request." But this is exactly why you normally put response assertion under each request, not under module. So I don't understand what kind of design you have and what you are trying to achieve.